# Twilio SMS and Survey

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am using Twilio to communicate with my users via SMS.  I have my own web application that reads the incoming Twilio message. I use a web hook for that purpose.  I am able to read the incoming message and process it in my web application.

I would like to send out survey questions periodically during the day to the same number.  I researched the Studio flow for this purpose. It looks like a good option to write a survey.

I have a doubt though.  In twilio console I added my url as a web hook to receive all sms messages.  If I build a studio flow then how do I use that.  I already have a web hook but I also want to do a survey using the same twilio phone number.  Is there a way to do this in Twilio.

What I want to achieve is I receive SMS from a twilio number all through the day using a web hook.  Every 2 hours or so I would like to send out a survey question to the same twilio number and process the answer     in my end.  What is the best approach to do this? I use c# and .net core to write my web app.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can do this.

You would use the REST API path of the Studio Trigger widget of your Studio Flow, to kick off this outbound SMS. You can find more details below. The scheduling logic, every 2 hours, would be handled by your application logic.

[Trigger a Twilio Studio Flow Execution via the REST API](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007778153-Trigger-a-Twilio-Studio-Flow-Execution-via-the-REST-API)

[Execution](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/execution)

We use the REST API trigger for the [Appointment Reminder](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/how-to-send-appointment-reminders) Studio example.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I followed your idea and created a studio flow and was able to kick the execution flow from my code.  The question is being asked but now when I answer the execution stops . It is not flowing through the rest of the steps. The one thing that is confusing me is where I add the web hook in this link. https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/    Messages -> A Message Comes in.  I still have Webhook selected here and it is pointing to my originally created webpage. I want to keep this as is.  So how do I force the execution to go through the rest of the steps.

Comment: You can only have one URL in that field. The Webhook URL or your Studio Flow URL.  Can you purchase a different Twilio number for this purpose? You could adjust your application to return a HTTP Redirect to the Studio flow but somehow you need to decide what goes where. Not a common configuration.

Comment: Yes, I could purchase a different url and have a studio flow in that. So if that is the case how do you suggest I do a Http Redirect in my application.  Also, just to understand is the common method to have sms come via one twilio phone number and the survey or appointment come through a different phone number.  The main reason the studio is convenient is because I can check the answer provided by the user to make sure it is a valid one.  A plain SMS is stateless and it makes it hard to match the question and answer sent out by the user.  If there is a different approach please let me know.

Comment: Why not put it all in Studio. I don't see what your application is doing.

Comment: I have a Twilio number.  User send all kinds of SMS (including video, photos) to that.  I store all this in my end using web hook.  Periodically I want to check in on the user's pain level, happiness, mood etc.  I sent out a survey asking the user to rate mood etc. Currently I just compare the time I sent the question to twilio and the time I get a reply and then try to figure if the use is answering the survey (not a good solution).  Twilio Studio has some good examples for survey.  Without messing the webhook that collects data I want to combine both.  Not sure what to use. Any ideas?

Comment: I still believe you can send everything to Studio and use either the HTTP Request Widget or Run Function Widget to then communicate with your application as well as the Send or Send and Wait for Reply Widget to communicate with your user. That would consolidate everything in one place. You are correct with SMS being stateless. The Send and Wait for Reply Widget does wait for a response before proceeding to the next widget.

Comment: I am trying to follow your idea.  So I created a split based on widget.  When a message comes in if it is not a survey question, this message can be a video or multiple images or a plain text sms I want to divert it to my code in c#.  So I use a httprequest widget and  I set it to Post and the url to my web api.  I am able to trigger this with out any issues.  Now how do I access all the incoming details. I can see the details in the log under flow data -> trigger -> Message.  But I don't know how to get all this in my c# call. When I used web hook I used to grab the HttpRequest object .

Comment: In the log it looks something like this.  I want to gather all of this data in my code. What am I missing?
      "MediaUrl1": "Url",
      "MediaUrl0": "url",
      "SmsSid": "id",
      "SmsStatus": "received",     
      "NumSegments": "2",
      "From": "+1208xxx",
      "ToState": "DC",
      "MessageSid": "MMxxx",
      "AccountSid": "ACxxx",
      "FromCountry": "US",
      "FromZip": "zip",
      "MediaContentType1": "image/jpeg",
      "Body": "",
      "ToCountry": "US",
      "FromState": "state",
      "NumMedia": "2",
      "MediaContentType0": "image/jpeg"

Comment: So you are using the HTTP Request Widget? You can send the other parameters in the flow by using liquid syntax to refer to them. Just POST them to your application as HTTP Parameters from the HTTP Widget. You can see the path for the values of the keys in the Execution logs of your Twilio Studio Flow. https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide/liquid-template-language.